# Accessing Network Adapter Settings in .NET

Tags: .net, wmi

This is what i want to do:

- Configure my network adapters settings in C#

And it works quite fine, settings and reading and IPs, activating dhcp. I'm using System.Management classes for that.

Now what i want to do next is activate and deactivate things like "QoS Packet Planner", "Client for Microsoft Networks" and "E/A Driver for..." since my windows is in german, i can't say what those entrys are called exactly in english and i dont know what that list is called which makes it difficult to find information about it.

What i need now is:

- **the exact english technical name of that checkboxlist**

Answer (score 1):

this checkboxlist is the **list of bound protocols of a network adapter**. And as far I know there is not a WMI class to manipulate these entries.